# How to use/implement pause() to pause a SKAudioNode?

Tags: audio, sprite-kit, skaudionode

The documentation:

> **pause()**
>
> Creates an action that tells an audio node to pause playback.
>
> **Declaration** class func pause() -> SKAction
>
> This action may only be executed on an SKAudioNode object. The audio
>   is paused, and if restarted, resumes at where it was paused. This
>   action is not reversible.

Please excuse my ignorance, I simply have no idea how to use this to pause an `SKAudioNode`, so have not tried any code, and have no code to display, as I don't know HOW to use this, and find this barebones documentation a little too light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SKAudioNode`s are `SKNode`s and so are able to `run` any `SKAction`. So get a pause action and ask the node to run it (in Swift):

```
let audio : SKAudioNode
...
let pause = SKAction.pause()
audio.run(pause)
```

or shorter:

```
audio.run(SKAction.pause())
```